# Inserting elements to a multi dimensional List throwing index out of range exception

Tags: c#, list

I am working on a `C# list` which is multi dimensional of type that I have created myself and I am trying to insert elements to that list from another list which for some reasons throwing Index was out of range exception when I trying to insert value into `0th` row using the following code

```
List<StructuresDS> listStructures = new List<StructuresDS>();
                    listStructures[0].time =Convert.ToDateTime(AxiomSubSet[0].time.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                    listStructures[0].CC = AxiomSubSet[0].CC;
                    listStructures[0].term = listCodedTerms[0];
                    listStructures[0].strike = (Convert.ToDouble(AxiomSubSet[0].strike) * 100).ToString();
                    listStructures[0].strategy = AxiomSubSet[0].strategy;
                    listStructures[0].premium = Convert.ToDouble(AxiomSubSet[0].price);
                    listStructures[0].volume = Convert.ToInt32(AxiomSubSet[0].quantity);
```

**May I know a reason for this behaviour and where  I am making a mistake?**

Comment: `listStructures` is empty, so there is no element at `listStructures[0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to set `listStructures[0]`, but it hasn't been added yet. You should just need to do something like:

```
List<StructuresDS> listStructures = new List<StructuresDS>();
listStructures.Add(new StructureDS 
                   {
                       time = Convert.ToDateTime(AxiomSubSet[0].time.ToString("HH:mm:ss")),
                       CC = AxiomSubSet[0].CC,
                       // etc.
                   });
```

Comment: Will the above code add each row when I place it in a loop or will replace the elements?

Comment: Looping and calling `.Add()` will add a new element to the list on each iteration. (Just make sure the first line is outside the loop.)

Answer (score 1):

I had to stub in values for both AxiomSubSet and listCodedTerms and assumed that AxiomSubset.time was a date but was a string in StructuresDS.  I also assumed that premium and volume were double and int respectively & everything else was a string, but the code below compiles and functions as expected for me.  I believe that your problem is that you're assuming there's a 0th element after the list has been instantiated but you've not added anything to it.  A listStructures.Add(new StructuresDS {...}) would also address the issue.

```
List<StructuresDS> listStructures = new List<StructuresDS> { 
    new StructuresDS {
                    time = Convert.ToDateTime(AxiomSubSet[0].time.ToString("HH:mm:ss")),
                    CC = AxiomSubSet[0].CC,
                    term = listCodedTerms[0],
                    strike = (Convert.ToDouble(AxiomSubSet[0].strike) * 100).ToString(),
                    strategy =  AxiomSubSet[0].strategy,
                    premium = Convert.ToDouble(AxiomSubSet[0].price),
                    volume =Convert.ToInt32(AxiomSubSet[0].quantity)
                    }
};
```

To test that the object was created as expected and the 0th element of the list contains the expected values, I wrote each property of the object to the console using the form below:

```
Console.WriteLine(listStructures[0].time.ToString());
```

Does that work for you when you apply it to your environment?